# If 5 boys write 5 pages in 5 minutes, then 3 boys will write 3 pages in how many minutes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If 5  boys write 5 pages in 5 minutes, then 3 boys will write 3 pages in how many minutes?

Answer Options are: 
i) 1 minute
ii) 3 minutes
iii) 5 minutes
iv) 9 minutes

The correct answer is: 5 minutes. 
Reasoning: There would be no change in time.

PS - I am confused with this reasoning.

According to me, using the unitary method, time should be 1.8 minutes. What am I missing?

Comment: I suppose what they have in mind is that a boy takes five minutes to write a page. If you have $n$ boys and give them five minutes, you get one page from each, total $n$ pages.

Comment: Perhaps they delegate one boy to do all the writing, and the rest go off to play video games.  Or perhaps they have only one pen and must take turns.  Then it will be $3$ minutes.

Comment: This is an old puzzle.  Think how you get 1.8 minutes ... you ....actually I'm not sure how you did it but think about what units you are dividing by and think does that unit actually answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" *There would be no change in time.*"

That's true but it's not stated well and isn't clear why that would be so.

What they are getting at is this:  If one boy can write one page in some amount of time, it then $n$ boys can write $n$ pages in that same amount of time.  $n$ can be $3$, $5$, or two million.

So it takes $5$ boys $5$ minutes to write $5$ pages, then $1$ boy can write $1$ page in $5$ minutes and two million boys can write two million pages in $5$ minutes.  And $3$ boys  can write $3$ pages in $5$ minute.

In general:

Let $b$ = the number of boys.

$t \text{ mins}$  = the time in minutes.

$r \frac {\text{page}}{\text{min}}$  = the rate of that one boy can write a page.

and $P \text{ pages}$ = the number of pages written, you have the formula:

$P \text{ pages} = b*r\frac {\text{page}}{\text{min}}*t \text{ mins}$

So if $5 \text{ pages} = 5*r\frac {\text{page}}{\text{min}}*5 \text{ mins}$

What is $3 \text{ pages} = 3*r\frac {\text{page}}{\text{min}}*t \text{ mins}$?

Well, $5 \text{ pages} = 5*r\frac {\text{page}}{\text{min}}*5 \text{ mins}\implies$

$ r\frac {\text{page}} {\text {min}}= \frac {5 \text{ mins}}{5*5 \text{ pages}}= \frac 15 \frac {\text{page}}{\text {min}}$

So $3 \text { pages} = 3*\frac 15 \frac {\text{page}}{\text{min}}*t \text { mins} \implies$

$t \text { mins} = \frac{3 \text { pages}}{3*\frac 15 \frac {\text{page}}{\text{min}}}= 5\text { mins}$

Answer (score 1):

It would take the same amount of time for 5 boys to write 5 pages and 3 boys to write 3 pages. 1 Boy writes 1 page in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Not all things scale linearly. Each boy takes 5 minutes to finish his page, independent of the other boys. So 3 boys to write 3 pages would need 5 minutes still. 3 boys to write 4 pages would need 10 minutes total if they couldn't work together on writing a page, unless the 3 boys could work together on the last page.

Answer (score 0):

let's look at the ratio between the amount of pages to the amount of boys.

from the question we know:

$\frac{5 pages}{5boys}=5$

$\frac{5 pages}{5boys}=\frac{ 1page}{1boy}=\frac{3 pages}{3boys}=5$

you can think that every boy writes one page alone and that takes 5 minutes.